# While value is x

Tags: loops, powershell, while-loop, return-value

Being new to PowerShell, I have this script which works when using 'switch'. I tried to get it to work using 'while' but it exits whether the value is 1 or 0.

Looking at the script below, could someone point out to me where I am going wrong!!

Your help is appreciated.

```
cls
Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory
$ADpath = "OU=OU1,DC=DC1,DC=DC2,DC=DC3";
$i = 0

function yaynay(){
    $i = Read-Host "`nSearch again.." "Y `tOR N";
    switch -Regex ($i.ToUpper()){
        "Y(es)?"{$i -eq 1}
        default {$i -eq 0}
    }
    get-pssession | remove-pssession
}

function TableFormat(){
    $x1=@{label='Full Name';Expression={$_.name};width=20},
    @{label='Login Name';Expression={$_.samaccountname};width=15},
    @{label='OU';Expression={(($_.DistinguishedName -split "=",4)[3] -split ",",2[0]};width=15}
    $ADusr | Format-Table $x1
}

function getOut(){
    Write-Host "AD Search will now exit"
    exit
}

function ADUwrite (){
    Write-Output "`n Cannot find user:  $InputUsr"
}

while ($i -lt 1)
{
    $InputUsr = Read-Host "Enter One or More Letters To Search For User"
    $InputUsr1 = $InputUsr

    if($InputUsr -eq ""){
        write "`n No Search Criteria Entered... Exiting AD User Search"
        exit
    }

    $InputUsr = "*"+$InputUsr+"*"

    if([string]$InputUsr1 -contains "*"){
        $InputUsr = $InputUsr.Replace($InputUsr, $InputUsr1)
    }

    $ADusr = Get-ADUser -Filter {name -like $InputUsr} -SearchBase $ADpath
    $x=$ADusr.name.length

    if($x -gt 0){
        TableFormat
    }
    else{
        $InputUsr = $InputUsr1.ToUpper()
        ADUwrite $InputUsr
    };

    yaynay($i)
    if($i = 1){
        GetOut
    }

    Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Several things here:

```
function yaynay(){
    $i = Read-Host "`nSearch again.." "Y `tOR N";
    switch -Regex ($i.ToUpper()){
        "Y(es)?"{$i -eq 1}
        default {$i -eq 0}
    }
    get-pssession | remove-pssession
}
```

The variable `$i` is local to this function and is never returned so its value won't affect anything happening outside.

```
yaynay($i)
```

You don't use parentheses to call a Powershell function (though you do to call a method), it won't matter much here as it will just pass the number 0 as an argument, but if you try it with more than one argument you'll end up passing an array. `yaynay`doesn't have any arguments defined so it will ignore the argument anyway.

```
if($i = 1){
    GetOut
}
```

assigns the value `1` to the variable `$i`. This is always true so you'll always call `GetOut`. The comparison should be `if ($i -eq 1)`.

Comment: Also, `$i` in yaynay() is going to be string that likely contains 'Y' or 'N'.  It will never be equal to 1 or 0.  And it is kind of odd that a "yaynay" function would remove all PSSessions. Seems like a better approach is to have yaynay `return` a bool e.g. `if (yaynay) { GetOut }`.